# Creating sharing rules through apex not manual sharing

Tags: sharing, apex-managed-sharing, sharing-rule, apex-sharing, criteria-based-sharing

Is it feasible to create sharing rules through apex , not manual sharing of records?

Can someone please let me know if that can be done?

Comment: you have use metadata api

Comment: How that can be possible?

Comment: @SantanuBoral  I found this article exactly depicting my case and it results in no ultimate success.                                                                                                       https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000B28SIAS

Answer (score 1):

Not really. It's theoretically *possible* to do so, but not even Financialforce's MDAPI [supports SharingRule](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/issues/65). You would have to spend a significant amount of effort. For custom objects, you can use [Apex Managed Sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing.htm), and for standard objects, consider Apex-based manual sharing; it's relatively painless to perform in bulk, and is pretty easy to maintain. In fact, I've written a simple, but specialized, manual sharing application for my org. Depending on your needs, it's not too bad. Even then, I'd try to persuade you to look at alternative declarative options, like territory management, before you go down the dark path of automating sharing.

Comment: I found this article exactly depicting my case and it results in no ultimate success. developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000B28SIAS

Comment: @SFDC_Learner You are not the first to try, and you won't be the last, but basically, until the mdapi is more accessible in Apex, you should consider it impossible for all practical purposes. Also, consider that creating sharing rules is an asynchronous process. An automated process could theoretically lock up your org's setup and configuration page for *days* (last sharing rule we created took 16 hours to complete). Given there's no way to abort it, either, I'd be wary of trying to do this.

Comment: You mean manual sharing of records through share objects would be the best?

Comment: @SFDC_Learner Yes, even though they say "Manual", because we can't select any of the other picklist types, they're generated by way of a trigger that maintains the correct sharing. To make things easier, we also have a process that creates Public Groups for everyone that a record should be shared with. It's specialized, but only admins have access to sharing buttons in our org, so it works out well.